# Not able to add android support v4.jar

Tags: android, android-studio

I am not able to add the Android Support-V4 library. It is giving me the following error:

> Error:(245, 56) error: incompatible types
>
> required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager found:
>   android.app.FragmentManager

When i try to add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+'  // This one i am trying to add
}
```

Same error comes. Please give me a solution.

Comment: Have you installed the support library via SDK Manager?

Answer (score 1):

> required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager found:
>   android.app.FragmentManager

is not a problem with the library.
most likely you call

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

in your Activity.
Change it to

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

or edit your imports in your activity:

> import android.app.FragmentManager -> import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Answer (score 1):

Replace **import android.app.FragmentManager;**

to

**import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;**

your import is wrong as you are using dependency

**compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.+'**

Update import in Fragment as above.

Comment: Yess, after this i change : FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();  to android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();   and it works .... thanks a lot :)